# driver: How to select third combo box available in the page

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I have three combo boxes present on the page and I have to click the third one and select options from it.

I have code for clicking random. please let me know how to modify this code to select third combo box.

```
List<WebElement> list = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".select2-selection__arrow"));
Random r = new Random();
int randomvalue = r.nextInt(list.size());
System.out.println(randomvalue);
list.get(randomvalue).click();
```

Comment: Please share the html.

Comment: If those 3 boxes are wrapped in separate containers, you can limit the scope to the third one and then select the combobox. Or you can use xpath.

Comment: No all the three are wrapped in a single container....

Comment: Not sure but you can try some thing like this : list[2].get(randomvalue).click();

Comment: list[2].get(randomvalue).click () is not working .. the dropdown is not selected

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generating random integers in a specific range](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/363681/generating-random-integers-in-a-specific-range)

Comment: The problem is that according to the docs, the max value is excluded. `nextInt(int n) 
          Returns a pseudorandom, uniformly distributed int value between 0 (inclusive) and the specified value (exclusive), drawn from this random number generator's sequence.`

Comment: list.get(randomvalue).click(); --> list.get(2).click();